# retrieve XML to excel based on matching string

Tags: xml, vba

I have a log file which consists of several xml requests and responses. My requirement is to find a string whether it is present in any of the xml reqsts/responses in the log file and retrieve the xml if string is present using VBA (Excel Macro). Could some one help on this?

Note: Log file is not in .xml format. It's file extension is .LOG.Right now I'm handling it as a text file

Sample format of Log file :

```
[8/9/2015:12:00]<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UFT-8"?>
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns="https://schemas.xmlsoap.org/"><soapenv:Header.....>
    .
    .
    <validity message-id="ABC12345678">
    .
    </validity>
    .
    .</soapenv:envelope>
    [8/9/2015:12:44]<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UFT-8"?>
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns="https://schemas.xmlsoap.org/"><soapenv:Header.....>
    .
    .
    <validity message-id="PQR12345678">
    .
    </validity>
    .
    .</soapenv:envelope>
```

I'm looking to retrieve xml with message-id=PQR12345678

Comment: Need to see sample of xml.  Not too difficult.

Comment: Your reference for this Microsoft XML X.X (6.0 is the latest i think)

Answer (score 0):

This code may get you started.

```css
'add reference Microsoft XML, v6.0
Public Sub DownloadFile()
    Dim objWHTTP As Object
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim arrData() As Byte
    Dim lngFreeFile As Long
    
    
    
    On Error Resume Next
        Set objWHTTP = CreateObject("WinHTTP.WinHTTPrequest.5")
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            Set objWHTTP = CreateObject("WinHTTP.WinHTTPrequest.5.1")
        End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    URL = "Enter your URL or filename here"
    
    objWHTTP.Open "GET", URL, False
    objWHTTP.send
    arrData = objWHTTP.responseBody
    strData = StrConv(arrData, vbUnicode)
    
    Dim xmlbook As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60

    xmlbook.LoadXML strData
End sub​
```

Comment: Good suggestion but as you commented, it really depends on structure of xml file. MSXML's LoadXML only handles element-centric XML files, not attribute-centric and OP seems to request attribute value: `message-id=PQR12345678`. Also, you can late bind without reference of MSXML, v6: `Dim xmlbook As Object   Set xmlbook = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument60")`

Comment: I agree.  Used code that was taking data from a webpage.  The code needs to be changed if xml is from a file.

Comment: XML is from a file(.log extension) but not from a webpage.